# Error while passing data from view to controller in ci

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am facing an Internal Server Error : 500, While I try to pass the values from my view to code igniter controller. I am trying to pass it through the ajax scripts. I do not know how to debug and see through the browser as to what is happening in the controller. Kindly help me out!. I am kind of jammed.. I would be great if you show me in a fiddle.

This is my view code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/login/style.css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oleo+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/login/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
javascript:window.history.forward(1);
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#logincheck").click(function(){
        var action = $("#lg-form").attr('action'); 
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        //alert($("#username").val());
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: action,
            data: {u_name : username,pwd : password},
            success: function(response)
            { //$('#message').html(response).fadeIn('slow');
                if(response == "success")
                    location.href = "<?php echo site_url();?>/Dashboard/index";
                else
                $("#message").html('<p class="error">ERROR: Invalid username and/or password.</p>');
            }   
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="lg-container">
<h1>Admin Area</h1>

<form action="<?php echo site_url('login/login_check');?>" id="lg-form" name="lg-form" method="post">

        <div>
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="username"/>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password" />
        </div>

        <div style="text-align:center;">                
            <button type="submit" id="logincheck">Login</button>
        </div>
        </form>
    <div id="message"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my Controller code is :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('login_page/login');
    }
public function login_check()
    {   print_r($this->input->post());exit;
        $res['username'] = $this->input->get('u_name');
        $res['password'] = md5($this->input->get('pwd'));

        $this->load->model('Login_m');
        $i=$this->Login_m->login_data($res);
        if($i ==1 )
        {
            echo "success";
        }
    }
}
```

And My Model Code is :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login_m extends CI_Model
    {

    function login_data($data)
        { //print_r($data);exit;

            $query =$this->db->query('select e.* from ins_entity e where e.entity_uname =? and e.entity_pwd =?',array($data['username'],$data['password']))->row_array();
            if(count($query) > 0)
            {   

                        $newdata = array(
                        'id' => $query['entity_id'],
                        'name' => $query['entity_name'],
                        'uname' => $query['entity_uname']);
                        $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);                 
                         return 1;
            }
            else
             {
                //echo "Invalid Credentials at present";
                return 0;

             }
        }   

    }


?>
```

Comment: Hey, have you ever try to pass form action: index.php/login/login_check? try this its works for me while call controller function with ajax.

Comment: yes i have passed in the url form action only

Comment: I means to say try form action index.php/login/login_check instead of login/login_check, because its work for me in my project.

Comment: Find logs and post here will save many times

Comment: I do not know how to debug and know in controller. can anyone help me to debug

Comment: Don't use md5 for passwords not safe easy to hack use php http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out the solution for the issue.  I did two mistakes in my programming

1. Initially, I was unable to debug in my chrome browser. So, For Debugging i did by 'pressing F12', I went to the 'Network' tab and clicked the 'All' option. Else 'XHR' was enough for me.
2. In my autoload.php inside the ci, I forgot to add the 'database','session' helpers.

   After I corrected these two things, I did not get the Internal Server Error : 500, While I try to pass the values from my view to code igniter controller. Thanks for all those who helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, instead of using

```
var action = $("#lg-form").attr('action');  // YOU dont need this
var username = $("#username").val();
var password = $("#password").val();
```

Instead use

```
var data = $("#lg-form").serialize() //should be logincheck
```

You have a strange naming convention. The ID of your form should be more descriptive of the form.

This doesnt line up with your form

```
$("#logincheck").click(function(){
```

On your form it says the ID is lg-form. The ID should be logincheck on the form too